# What are the possible causes where a task is successfully created, but it didn't get added to the queue in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

Tags: task, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

When a task is successfully created it is supposed to be added to the queue of the thing that created that task. But what are the possible reasons that a task is not appearing in the queue?

Comment: Did you verify my answer?

Comment: How are you creating the Task? manually / via workflow / via code - what type of code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not creating `queueitem` record or somehow your existing automation is broken. That’s why task record is not showing up in queue.

Queue is a container to keep all the activities/records in track, but the actual activity/record will not be associated in Queue but the Queue Item record.

Make sure to create a queueitem record for your task & set it to the right queue.

[Read more](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/05/24/assign-owner-and-route-case-to-queue-using-workflow-in-dynamics-crm/)